# How to disable snap package warning for root user?

Tags: kali-linux, configuration, snap

I would like to disable the following warning for the root user.

```
You are trying to start Visual Studio Code as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please add the argument `--no-sandbox` and specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument.
```

I do not want to have to enter the --no-sandbox argument every time I run a snap. And I don't want to alias all of them. I am well aware of the security risks. I will only be doing this in a VM for personal use.
Is there any way to edit a config file or something to bypass this error?

Comment: But you **are** running vscode as root, which sounds like a very bad idea, not only security-wise, but practically, as well, so honestly, I'd recommend keeping the warning in place and asking a different question, namely how to solve whatever problem you're solving by running vscode as root.

Comment: Other than that, the warning already tells you how to get rid of the warning, I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: I would like to edit the config somehow so that it doesn't prompt for that '--no-sandbox' parameter and just run instead. So it would function automatically as it would as a regular user. I am well aware of the security concerns. I am only doing this on kali Linux for CTFs. So I am not worried about security issues because I could just revert to a snapshot.

Comment: still makes no sense to run it as root, sorry.

Comment: (seriously, what is the reason you'd need to run VSCode as root, **especially** on Kali linux? This just feels like you're missing something easy, like mounting other file systems with a umask, or just… not using root when you don't need it. This isn't about security, this is about finding complicated solutions to easy problems :) I'm sure we *can* bent snapd to your will, *somehow*, but it's probably harder than actually solving the problem you think you need to solve by running VSCode as root.)

Comment: Anyway, removing the wrong [tag:ubuntu] and replacing it with [tag:kali-linux]. Kali is not Ubuntu! The two distributions are *not* compatible.

Comment: I am not asking if it makes sense. I just want to know if it is possible. The only way I found so far is to create a python 'run' program that injects the --no-sandbox argument and then executes the program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created this python3 workaround.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print("No snap specified")
        exit(-1)
    else:
        os.system(sys.argv[1] + " --no-sandbox " + ' '.join(sys.argv[2:]))
        exit(0)
```

Add to PATH

Example:

run code --user-data-dir ~/.vscode .

Comment: You're recommending to use root to edit files in your home directory, which makes newly created files inaccessible to your own user. You're literally creating a problem by doing so. At least put the data files somewhere else than the default path for them in your own user's home!

Comment: The way you do this now you make it impossible to run code as your normal user.

Comment: On my VM I am the only user. But I see what you mean.